# TensorFlow is reading my input images as an array where every element is the same number

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, image-classification

I am trying to write an image classifier using tensor flow and when I am reading in the images (which are all png files) it is creating an array where every element is the same number. This shouldn't be the case and I don't know why this is happening.

He is the code I used:

```
#creates a random batch of data

data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir, batch_size=10)
data_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()
batch = data_iterator.next()
print(batch)
batch[0].shape
```

And its output looks something like this:

```
Found 100 files belonging to 2 classes.
(array([[[[255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.],
         ...,
         [255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.]],

        [[255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.],
         ...,
         [255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.]],

        [[255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.],
         ...,
         [255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255.]],

        ...,
```

All of these values should not be 255 and I don't know why they are.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LJLf.jpg)

Comment: Edit your question instead of making comments. You can always edit your own questions.  Also this is not reproducible without one of your image files.